# Using EF (not EF Core) with .NET 6 or above

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, but I have some legacy libraries I have to use that are dependent on EF 6 (not EF Core).

I see in those libraries dbcontext is getting initialised with parameterless constructors i.e. not passing connection string, dbOptions, etc.

I see it defaulting to localdb for dbserver.

```
 using (var context = new AppSettingDb())
 {
     var item = context.AppSettings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SettingName == settingName);
     if (item == null) throw new AppSettingException() { AppName = _appName, SettingName = settingName };
     return item.Value;
 }
```

Is there anyway of changing the default connection string to be used when context is created? I tried to add a `web.config` to my .NET 6 project, it did not work.

Comment: .NET/.NET Core reads configuration settings from appsettings.json instead of the old web.config. as used by .NET Framework. Try adding your connection string there. (Not sure if it will actually work but worth a try.)

Comment: No @phuzi EF (none core) doesnt seem to get anything from app.config .

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class AppSettingDb : DbContext
{
    public AppSettingDb(String? connectionString = null)
        : base(connectionString ?? "server=localdb;database=db")
    {
    }
}
```

Not quite sure, but is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite. I cant really change/edit the shared legacy code.